# vba Dictionary - returning KEY from Items()

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each `VALUE` is another dictionary. In my code I loop through the top-level dictionary using `.Items()(i)`. By the way, it needs to stay this way.

```
Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim myValue As New Scripting.Dictionary

For i = 0 to dic.count-1
  ' 
  ' the VALUE of the KEY/VALUE pair is...
  set myValue = dic.Items()(i) 
  '
  ' how do I retrieve the KEY???
  '
Next i
```

**My question:**

How do I retrieve the KEY of the top-level dictionary in this loop structure? This is probably super obvious, I'm just drawing a blank here.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I never used .Keys(i) before. Thanks!

Comment: You can always loop through the `Keys` collection of the `Dictionary Object` using `For Each Loop`. That is what it's there for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d, i
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    d.Add "K1", "v1"
    d.Add "K2", "v2"
    d.Add "K3", "v3"

    For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
        Debug.Print d.items()(i), d.keys()(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

Or maybe this:

```
Dim key As Variant

With dic
    For Each key In .Keys
        Debug.Print key, .Item(key)
    Next
End With
```